# How to make Quick Time Player support .avi files?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, software-recommendation, video, quicktime

I have an **.avi** file that I wanted to play via **Quick Time Player** only.

But when I try to open an example **.avi** file, I get this error dialog pop-up given below:

[image]

**Note:** I know that I can use advanced media players like **VLC**, **Elmedia** and so on which has support for **.avi** files.

But I still want to use **Quick Time Player** for all video extension files (including non-supported too).

**Question:** Is there any plugin which can be installed in **Quick Time Player** to support **.avi** files?

Comment: The only one I've ever know that could do this was [Perian](https://perian.org), but that is long gone. I very much doubt that will work on any Mac since Catalina. Even they recommend VLC in their farewell note. AVI is pretty much a dead format these days, so I don't see there being any great impetus for developers to add it now.

Comment: @Tetsujin I agree with you completely. Actually, I was trying to use Perian with QT 10.5 but it didn't work for me. But I'm looking for a solution if someone has tried with a different plugin apart from Perian.

Comment: tbh, I think your time would be better spent throwing the file at a converter if you insist on QT playback - such as [Smart Converter](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/smart-converter/id447513724?mt=12) will do it for free, with simple target settings. If you want finer control, you can't beat [Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr/downloads.php)

Comment: @Tetsujin Let me try with the handbrake. I will let you know. Meanwhile, you add this as an answer.

Comment: Done. Wish you luck.

Comment: @Tetsujin I was able to convert the avi to mp4 quite easily. It's working fine. I was able to open the file.

Comment: Glad you got it - I do think sometimes it's easier to just flip your file type than fret over a compatibility aspect, especially if you're talking about some old movie or TV show in SD. The perceptual quality lost will be insignificant, compared to the convenience.

Comment: @Tetsujin I was earlier facing difficulties to convert avi via ffmpeg. Somehow the converted file was not working. Then, I tried looking for any plugin if QT can support via that. I'm okay with handbrake. I can convert all the old tv shows which are in avi format.

Comment: IIRC, Apple deliberately removed legacy formats from QuickTime and also got rid of plugins. At one point, I believe installation would offer to convert your videos to H264 for you.

Comment: AVI is a container format.  What matters is what the codec is inside.

Comment: @MarcWilson - sure, but if it refuses to even look inside the container, there's not a lot you can do. As far as I can see, Apple have over the years dropped more & more functionality from QT & haven't bothered with a single update since Mojave.

Comment: You can use e.g. `ffprobe` (installed with `ffmpeg`) to show the codec(s) used.  If they're also available in MPEG4, then you can use `ffmpeg` to do the conversion fast and losslessly; otherwise, the conversion is going to lose quality (and time and/or file size).

Comment: @gidds I was facing some issues with `ffmpeg` commands while converting from avi to mp4. Can you add that alternative as an answer too? I would love to see the `ffmpeg` way.

Comment: @AnishB. It would depend on what streams are in the AVI file, and what codecs they use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only one I've ever know that could do this was [Perian](https://perian.org/), but that is long gone. I very much doubt that will work on any Mac since Catalina. Even they recommend VLC in their farewell note. AVI is pretty much a dead format these days, so I don't see there being any great impetus for developers to add it now.

tbh, I think your time would be better spent throwing the file at a converter if you insist on QT playback - such as [Smart Converter](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/smart-converter/id447513724?mt=12) will do it for free, with simple target settings. If you want finer control, you can't beat [Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr/downloads.php).

Comment: VLC, MPV and MPlayer can play most file formats, old and new, including AVI. They also support dozens of audio and video codecs.